# How to change the color of a pixel in HSV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the infamous yoshi image in HSV and I want to change the color of the pixels in certain parts of the image.

```
cv::cvtColor(frame, frame_hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

for (int y = 0; y < mask.size().height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < mask.size().width; x++) {

        cv::Vec3b pixelM = mask.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(x, y));

        if ((pixelM[0] == 255) && (pixelM[1] = 255) && (pixelM[2] = 255)) { // If white
            cv::Vec3b& pixelF = frame_hsv.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(x, y));
            pixelF[0] = 280;
            pixelF[1] = 100;
            pixelF[2] = 100;
            
        }
    }
}
cv::cvtColor(frame_hsv, frame, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);
```

Here `frame` is the original yoshi image and `mask` is the image that shows me where exactly to change the color of the pixel. The color is changing exactly where I want BUT the color, that I am expecting is different. In the image (output) below you see a "dirty green" but I am expecting a purpe color (HSV: 280, 100, 100). Why is the color not being set correctly?

[yoshi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Gve.png)
[yoshi attempted color red and Hue/2 (HSV: 180, 100, 100)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw9zN.png)

Comment: In 8 bit channels, opencv uses hue values from 0 to 180 instead of 0 to 360, so divide your hue color value by 2

Comment: @Micka thank you for your help. I uploaded a second picture. It doesn't quite get the output, that I want. I tried it with red (Hue=360/2=180). When I am getting is rather a "dirty" red.

Comment: Which hsv color value do you want to set? In your code ot is (280,100,100), which is a dirty purple (dirty because saturation and value only 100). So if you try (280/2,100,100) you should end up with that dirty purple pixel in opencv.

Comment: If you want a bright color, choose (hue/2, 255, 255)

Comment: @opennime as you can see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html), Value and Saturation have ranges [0;255]  so to make your color 'not dirty', try using values 255 for them